# How to dyanmic create a new entity (table) and Model in Coredata

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I building an app dictionary, in this app data of dictionary is json and it will be stored in my server. User buy dictionary, and it will be parsed to coredata. My database structure is have `Dictionary(type,name)` and table store database dictionary `NameDictionary(word, def)`. Example: User downloaded dictionary `en-en`, I will have 2 tables in coredata are `Dictionary(type,name)` and `English(word,def)`, if I get one more dictionary (ex:`en-fr`) my coredata will be added an table `France(word, def). So, my problem is:`Could I can create an entity and Model class of this entity dynamically via code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You can have an entity called `Dictionaries` with 2 attributes: `type`, `name` and another entity `Definitions` with attributes: `word`, `def`, `type` and add a relationship between the two entities. Then when a user buys a dictionary, you add a new Dictionary with type `en-en` and name: `"English-English"` and then add the definitions for all words for the type `en-en`.

Comment: Thanks guy, If I do like this, I will increase number of record of `Definitions` table rapidly, and it will be make record duplicated when user download another dictionary. Ex: first, User download `en-en`(100.000 words) -> `Defination` table will have 100.000 records, and then, User download `en-fr`(150.000 words) --> So, number of record of `Defination` is 250.000 records, and it will be get duplication. Could u give me some idea to resolve that problems. Thanks so much.

Comment: How will the duplication occur? Even if you have 2 words with 2 definitions which are the same, they will have different type: one will be en-en, the other one will be en-fr. And also you can mark some attributes as indexed which will increase performance when searching and also databases are created to handle millions of records, so I don't think you should worry...